# Is Stack Overflow paying Google to display ads about Stack Overflow on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, advertising

While browsing Stack Overflow, I stumbled upon this funny ad from Stack Overflow itself.

[image]

Hovering over the ad shows a `googleads.g.doubleclick.net` URL. So, is Stack Overflow paying Google to display ads about Stack Overflow on Stack Overflow?

Comment: So, if we click that ad, does SO get money from SO for advertising SO on SO?

Comment: SO doesn't use Google ads.  They do their own ads.

Comment: (I'm pretty sure these ads aren't hosted by google. Afaik, they're hosted by SO)

Comment: if you do mouse over it shows a url starting with googleads, does that imply it is google ads?

Comment: Note that most visitors of meta don't see banner ads...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I wish Google paid us for that ad ;) This is our internal ad to help developers find remote jobs via [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&l=Remote&d=20&u=Miles). The Google URL you saw came from [our new Google ad server](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301524/all-sites-will-be-switching-ad-servers-on-october-1) that served the ad.

Comment: "I wish Google paid us for that ad ;) " I dunno if that's a good idea. Sounds a lot like it would result in infinite recursion. We could run the world out of money.